# How do I mark a word as rare?

Tags: spell-checking

Vim has the commands `zg` and `zw` to mark a word as good (correctly spelled) or bad (incorrectly spelled), respectively. Is there a similar command to mark a word as rarely-used?

(It’s possible to manually append the word plus `/?` to the spell file, but this is a lot less convenient than just putting the cursor on the word and typing a couple of keys.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since [8.1.1838](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/08cc374dabd2a02785129fa1c0100f7745c244ad) (Aug 2019) you can use the `:spellrare` command, before that there is no way, other than manually editing the `~/.vim/spell/en.utf-8.add` file.